# How to find the middle node of a single linked list in a single traversal (if the length of the list is not given)

Tags: c++, linked-list

I have a problem statement like: "How to find the middle node of a singly linked list in only one traversal, and the twist is we don't know the number of nodes in the linked list?"

I have an answer like "take a vector and start pushing all the nodes' addresses as and when you are traversing the linked list and increment a counter till you reach the end of the list".  So at the end we can get the number of nodes in the list and if even (counter/2) or if odd (counter/2 + counter%2) gives the middle node number and with this we can get `vectore.at(middlenodenumber)` points to the middle node".

This is fine...but this is waste of memory storing all the address of a very large linked list!  So how can we have a better solution?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Following are the steps:

- Take two pointers `*p1` and `*p2` pointing to the head of linked
  list
- Start a loop and increment `*p2`, 2 times (with null checks)
- If `*p2` is not null then increment `*p1` 1 time
- When `*p2` reaches null; you have got the `*p1` at the center

[Note: You can use iterators instead of pointer if you deal with container type linked list]

Comment: While this is surely the desired answer, I never understood why it's consider a single traversal. It's really two (or 1.5) traversals in parallel and no fewer pointer/iterator increments than two (1.5) serial traversals. It's avoiding a counter but not any traversing.

Answer (score 10):

Say you have a `std::list<T> l`.

```
std::list<T>::iterator i = l.begin();
std::list<T>::iterator m = l.begin();
bool even = true;
while (i != list.end())
{
  if (even) ++m;
  ++i;
  even = !even;
}
```

Now `m` point to the middle of `l`.

Comment: After first `advance b` you must check for the null. Otherwise crash !

Comment: Depends on the precise problem statement. If it's given that there's an exact middle of the list, its length must be odd. You can then `advance b` before the loop.

Comment: @iammilind Pseudocode cannot crash :) But you're right, I replaced the code with C++, that illustrates and solves the problem you described.

Comment: how can we take care of a linked list if it has even number of nodes in it..it give to crash ri8 if we dont check out for null before proceeding!

Answer (score 1):

You can use a single loop with two iterators, say `it1` and `it2`, where you increment `it2` only every second iteration of the loop. Terminate when `it1` has reached the end of the list. `it2` will now point to the middle element of the list.

Comment: This was my first idea, but is it still "only one traverse"?

Comment: Yes it is, because you only have one loop. If this is homework, I do not know if it is what the assignment aims at, but for all practical purposes, this traverses the list once.

Comment: The REAL answer should be this, 'cause the current answer keeps the single-traverse rule only formally if you consider the task from the loop construct. But the actual number of scans are at least 1.5N.

Comment: I don't see any difference between my answer and the accepted answer, they do the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
You have 2 pointers. one points to mid, and the other to the end, both point to beginning of the list at start. Every second time you successfully increment the end pointer you increment mid a once, until you end pointer reaches the end.

Answer (score 0):

Use two pointers. Move first pointer by two nodes and second pointer by one node. When the first pointer reaches the end the second pointer will point to the middle.

Answer (score 0):

```
// How to find the middle node of a single linked list in a single traversal
//     1. The length of the list is not given
//     2. If the number of nodes is even, there are two middle nodes,
//        return the first one.
Node* MiddleNode(Node* const head)
{
    if (!head)
    {
        return head;
    }

    Node* p1 = head, * p2 = head->next;

    while (p2 && p2->next)
    {
        p1 = p1->next;
        p2 = p2->next->next;
    }

    return p1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SLNode* mid(SLNode *head) 

{

SLNode *one = head;

SLNode *two = head;


    while(one != nullptr) {
        one = one->next;
        two = two->next;
        if(one != nullptr) {
            one = one->next;
            //two = two->next;
        }
    }
    return two;
}
```

try this code