# Given a single linked list with an odd number of nodes, what are 2 ways of finding middle node by traversing list only once?

Tags: c++, list, linked-list

This was asked in an IBM ISL interview.

I went through the question, [How to find the middle node of a single linked list in a single traversal (if the length of the list is not given)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6703880/how-to-find-the-middle-node-of-the-single-linked-list-in-single-traversal-if-le) but it does not contain the answer I am looking for so posting here again.

I have a single linked list, let us say number of nodes are odd. Tell me 2 ways of finding middle node by traversing list only once?

I answered, take 2 pointers p1 & p2 move p2 by 2 nodes and p1 by 1 node. When p2 is null, p1 is at middle node.

Interviewer responded: That’s the simplest way using 2 pointers. Tell me one more way. Hint: is there a compiler property that can be used?

Can someone give me a way using the hint?

Comment: Compiler property? Is this C++?

Comment: That first solution sounds to me like traversing the list 1.5 times.

Comment: @RandyLevy, yes

Answer (score 5):

```
#include <vector>
#include <list>

typedef std::list<int> listT;

listT::const_iterator
find_middle(const listT &list)
{
  std::vector<listT::const_iterator> v;
  for (listT::const_iterator i = list.begin() ; i != list.end() ; ++i)
    v.push_back(i);

  return v[v.size() / 2];
}
```

Comment: That's going to throw std::fit(); when the list is empty. I think you can fix it by just adding v.push_back(list.begin()) before the loop. That would change the definition of what the "middle" is of a loop with an even number of elements.

Comment: ... but that is easily fixed too. Left as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: @JiveDadson - The question stipulated that the number of nodes is odd, so I figured it is ok to assume that.  In real life, you are right it would be better to validate the assumption